# Bash Variable inside double quotes inside single quotes - Common Expression Language

Tags: linux, bash, unix, common-expression-language

I need to put variable inside a double quotes inside single quotes.

I want to create common expression language like below.

```bash
passbolt list resource --filter 'FolderParentID == "**some-imaginary-id**"'
```

Just help replace **some-imaginary** with some bash variable.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate separate strings via juxtaposition (i.e., putting them directly next to each other, with no intervening whitespace).

```
passbolt list resource --filter 'FolderParentID == "'"$some_variable"'"'
```

Note there are three separate quoted strings:

1. `FolderParentID == "`, in single quotes
2. `$some_variable`, in double quotes
3. `"`, in single quotes

Regardless of the type of quotes used to quote each of the three, the *results* are concatenated into a single word.

At the expense of a command substitution, might want to use `printf` to generate the string for you.

```
passbolt list resource --filter "$(printf 'FolderParentID == "%s"' "$some_variable")"
```

Here you *can* "nest" the double quotes, because the command substitution starts a new quoting context: the first `"` inside the command substitution does *not* close the initial `"` that contains the command substitution.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do:

```
id=12345
echo passbolt list resource --filter "FolderParentID == '$id'"
```

```
passbolt list resource --filter FolderParentID == '12345'
```

Comment: That assumes the filter can use single quotes instead of double quotes.